# How to rebuild view loaded from nib into new frame size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nib

I'm trying to attach a view loaded from a nib file into another view.
let say first view is `subView` and the second is `containerView`.

When I added the `subView` to  container view using `addSubView` method, the subview has its content size and so appears truncated.

when I try to set the frame of the subview to containerView frame, it takes the frame but this brake the `autolayout`  in other words the subView constraints got meaningless.

How can I rebuild the `subView` in its new frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it, using 2 UIViewControllers, a container vc and a content vc. This method is in the container view controller:

```
- (void) displayContentController:(UIViewController*)contentViewController
{
    [self addChildViewController:contentViewController];

    contentViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame;

    [self.view addSubview:contentViewController.view];

    [contentViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

In my app, autolayout for the content works perfectly in all orientations and size classes.